# How to use tab in rails

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, css, tabs

i wanna ask bout tabs in rails...
so, i have a problem with the tab.
i'm goin to make tabs like this :

```
 <h2> Users </h2>
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="user-profile">
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#all", data-toggle="tab">
      All
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#investor", data-toggle="tab">
      Investor
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
      <a href="#volunteer", data-toggle="tab">
      Volunteer
      </a>
    </li>
 </ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="all" class="tab-pane">
    <% if @user_profiles != nil %>
      <% @user_profiles.each do |user_profile| %>
        <ul id="list-user" class="list-user thumbnails pull-right">
          <li class="span3 content-user"> 
            <%= image_tag user_profile.image.url, :size => '48x48', :class => "avatar avatar-48 photo" %>
            <div class="user-name">
              <span> <%= link_to (user_profile.full_name), user_profile %></span>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      <% end %>
    <% else %>
      <h3 class="text-center">Not Found</h3>
    <% end -%>
        </div>
    <div id="investor"  class="tab-pane">
      <h3 class="text-center">Not Found</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="volunteer"  class="tab-pane">
      <h3 class="text-center">Not Found</h3>
    </div>
```

when i click the all tab i want all user in my user_profile table are showing,
and if i click the volunteer tab, only user who has role id as volunteer are showing...
any ideas of my problem?
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For fetching all the users use `User.all` while for users having role volunteer use `User.find[:role => 'volunteer']`

Comment: sorry, i didn't get it :(